# Terraform, specifying location for vms on datastore

Tags: vmware-vsphere, directory, terraform, path, datastore

I was wondering as I couldn't find it in the documentation or I've missed it a lot.

I am using Terraform 0.12.9 with newest vsphere provider. My goal is to do a clone from a template and it basically works without any problem.

Requirement I am missing is to specify a folder(a local path on datastore) where vm is stored. By default it goes to /, however I would need to have it for example under /vms_xx/.

I've seen that you could create pre-existing disk and attach it, however it doesn't work with clone option.

Is it the case that you simply can't do it or am I missing something something? If it's #1, any workarounds you can suggest?

Regards,
Ricardo Sliva